# Suppress undefined name warning in Spyder?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

Being in the process of switching from Matlab to Python/IPython/Spyder I ran into the following issue.

In a Matlab script (and I actually did not notice this until I switched to Python) there is no warning if you are using a variable which you did not define in that script.

What I kept doing all the times in Matlab was to have, say, 2 (or more) scripts which I would then execute one after the other. The second script would typically use variables defined in the first, but would not give me any warning.

In Spyder I noticed that the situation is different. In my hypothetical second script, all the variables which are not defined in the second script itself give me a warning (undefined name '...'), which is not nice too see...

Another typical example, would be the following: I have a main script but there is something in this script I wanna look at better. So, without touching the script, I would create another file where I would copy paste a few lines from the script to play a little with them.
In this new file I would be using variables which are in the console already but that are techically unknown to the file itself, so would give me a warning.

So I guess I am simply asking if there a way to suppress this kind of warnings.

Or there might be a deeper question of whether there s a more pythonic way of working, but there I am really not sure about...

Comment: I don't understand. If the second module uses the variables from the first, without importing them, that isn't a *warning*. It is a run-time error. Using `import` is the general way to avoid such errors.

Comment: @JohnColeman It s simpler than that. I do not do any import. The mwe would be two files (both one-liners): first.py does "x=1" and second.py does "y=x+1". If I run first.py and then second.py, in that order, in the same console (pressing F5 in Spyder) they ll both run smoothly. But I ll see a warning in the editor in second.py. Which I do not wanna see.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to suppress those warnings at the moment. We'll try to fix that in a future release though.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I see. Can I somehow put in some kind of "enhancement request"? How can I do that? I guess this must be a standard procedure, but being a rookie I would not know exactly how to do it...

Comment: There's an issue already opened in our Github repo for that. It's being reported several times in the past but we haven't had time to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which I solved by wrapping the second script in a function.

first.py:

```
x=1
from second.py import myfunc
y = myfunc(x)
```

second.py:

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x + 1
```